# save List item from API in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app with two tabs,

when I open the first tap, the app gets data from API,

when I move to the second app and return to the first tab, the app connects to the API one more time to get the data,

what is the easier method to save the data from the first time??

Comment: plz provide the code you are using in implementing the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in the first tab :

```
class _FirstTabState extends State<FirstTab> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```